# Change powershell mode to STA in script

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, powershell-2.0, sta

I have a powershellscript which displays a WPF form using XAML. To execute this script, the powershell console have to be launched in STA mode (PS 2.0 default in MTA mode).

I know the opportunity, to change the mode in the console with this command:

```
powershell -sta
```

But in future my script will be executed automatically by an other programm without any parameter. So the console can't be called first with the -sta parameter.

Is there any opportunity to change the mode directly in the powershell script, befor the WPF/XAML is launched?

Comment: The threading model cannot be changed from within a running PowerShell instance, so you need to launch a new process with the desired threading model. That's what `powershell -sta` does: it starts a new PowerShell process in STA mode.

Comment: Thank you! So it's possible to start my scriptblock in the same powershellscirpt in a new process with powershell launched in STA mode? Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an simple example:

```
$x = {
    for($i= 0;$i -le 10;$i++){
        Write-host $i
    }
}

Start-Process Powershell.exe -argumentlist "-sta -NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $X"
```

Comment: Alternative you can start your script from a second script.

Comment: Thanks! I have tested your example and it works fine. But it seems to have problems when I smash my whole powershell gui code into the scriptblock variable. I get some errors after the new powershell process is started. However, I am using a workaround for this problem at the moment. I have created a second script, which calls powershell.exe with the STA and file parameter. --> powershell.exe -sta -file D:\Testdirectory\Powershell\ps_gui.ps1